# Close reason display bug, italics text is vertically offset a few px

Tags: bug, design, close-reasons, close-dialog

I've taken the following picture to demonstrate:

[image]

This is Chrome 28 in Ubuntu 13.04.

As you can see by the magnificent freehand circle, the *should*, which is wrapped in `<i>` tags (Really? Why not `<em>`? Seriously, I expected more). is offset from the rest of the line.

It's not present when the question is finally closed. As seen in the following example, on hold question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537801/process-of-making-twitter-bot-based-on-twitter-account

Comment: I noticed this also, thought it might've been deliberate because they're **emphasising** *so much* **there**, that [it's hard](http://localhost) **to figure out** *what is actually* **being emphasised**.

Comment: @TimStone: Right. Didn't notice that. Voted to close.